# Sorting Datagrid in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 5 columns in my datagrid? I want to sort the datagrid in ascending and decending order based on a particular column.

My question is, how do I implement sorting for only one column?

As the data in these column is of a string datatype, can numerical data be sorted?
any help appreciated.
thanks

Also, when I sort, it doesnt sort according to the numerical value in the column.

It's winforms.. btw, I got the solution.. i passed the values as strings thatsy it didnt sort numerically.. now it does.. thanks guyzz

Comment: Is the built in sort for the WPF Toolkit not what you need??

Comment: figured out how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a DataTable and a DataGridview then Sorting is built-in. For other situations, you need to add more info.